# Чернь - от слова "черный"?

Tags: этимология

То, что цвета играют в речи большую роль, ни для кого не секрет. Красный бывает синонимом красивого и одновременно раздражающего, белый - чистого и доброго, черный - злого, зеленый - слишком молодого. Но вот мне интересно слово "черный" в смысле, например, черной работы. А еще в плане обозначения простого народа - чернь. И ведь даже город такой есть (правда, я не знаю происхождения его названия). Но почему людей низшего сословия называли "чернью"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чернь - от "чёрные люди". По Ушакову - http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ushakov-term-83413.htm   .

9.Чёрный - принадлежащий к  "простому народу", к непривилегированным классам общества (•ист. ). Черный народ (•т.н. простонародье). Черная сотня (низшее сословие в древнем Новгороде). Черные люди -(др.-рус.) черный — тяглый, податный, тяглое население, платившее все виды государственных налогов и повинностей и жившее на черных землях в деревнях и городах России XII—XVII вв. К черным людям относились черносошные крестьяне, а также все население городских посадов, платившее налоги в отличие от «беломестцев». Формой организации черных людей в деревне были волостные, а в городах — посадские общины. Управлялись они кормленщиками. По своему социально-экономическому положению чёрные люди делились на "лучших", "средних" и "молодших". Термин "чёрные люди" вышел из употребления в начале 18 в.
Источник: Энциклопедия "Русская цивилизация"

10.Чёрный-в древней Руси - не частновладельческий, государственный (•ист. ). Черные земли. Черные люди или черные крестьяне (жившие на государственной земле). Черная соха .Черносошные люди - свободная часть крестьянского населения в России XIV—XVII вв. Название происходило от слов «черные люди» и «соха» (единица податного обложения). Черносошные крестьяне владели черными землями и платили все виды государственных налогов и повинностей. В XVIII в. черносошные крестьяне вошли в состав сословной группы государственных крестьян.
Источник: Энциклопедия "Русская цивилизация"

Оба значения, видимо, восходят к антонимической паре белая кость-чёрная кость.Белая-знатные люди, чёрная-низшие, второго сорта, выполняющие чёрную работу, т.е. неквалифицированную, тяжёлую (а тяжёлая всегда грязная, так что цвет всё равно играет свою семантическую роль)

Answer (score -1):

**Чернь** - самые бедные слои населения. Название происходит от понятия "топить по- чёрному", так как дым от печи выходил не через печную трубу, а через "оконце" в стене.

Comment: Мысль, конечно, интересная... Но разве везде,где жила "чернь", топили по-черному? Думаю, тут скорее само название способа отопления восходит к переносному значению "черный" - низкий, бедный, недостаточный, предварительный... (сравните - черновик). Остальное - в принятом ответе.